# Why do I have 0 edit suggestions approved and 0 edit suggestions rejected?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

After I reviewed some edits recently, I went back to my history to see how others treated those edits. To my surprise, I had 0 edit suggestions approved and 0 edit suggestions rejected in rejected edits. Example (https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/448146):

[image]

But ~300 short of proper numbers in approved edits:

[image]

My total as seen in the bar is 2358, but 1438 + 594 = 2032. I'd guess this might because of skipped edits.

Comment: @Dronehinge Heisenbug, I suppose.